# How to pass parameters to the function called by clone()?

Tags: c, parameters, clone

I have to use the clone() system call in the main-function to get 2 threads. (I know, there are other options, but in this case, it has to be clone()).

The system call works and both threads arrive in the designated function (foo). But in this function I need them to call another function with this signature:

```
void increment(int* a, int b)
```

(Sidenote: It adds b * 1 to a. (= a+b))

The important thing is, that both, a and b, are declared in the main-function and I don't know how to pass them to foo.

I already tried different things, but without success. I've gotten a hint: Use an adapter.
But I have no clue how to do this. (I also dont know how to use the args in clone with int.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the arguments to `clone()` is a `void* arg`.  This lets you pass a void pointer to your function.  In order to pass an int pointer and an int instead, you have to create a struct with an int pointer and int assigned to `a` and `b` respectively, then cast a pointer to that struct into a void pointer.  Then inside the function you reverse the process.

My C is a little rusty and I haven't compiled this, so don't quote me on it, but it should look roughly like this:

```
struct clone_args {
    int* a;
    int b
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct clone_args args;
    args.a = a;
    args.b = b;
    void* arg = (void*)&args;
    clone(fn, ..., arg, ...);
}

int fn(void* arg)
{
    struct clone_args *args = (struct clone_args*)arg;
    int* a = args->a;
    int b = args->b;
}
```

Note:  take care that the struct you create is still in scope when `fn` is called, as it isn't copied.  You might have to `malloc` it.

Comment: Ok thanks. The biggest trouble was to somehow get information into that void pointer. I will try this tomorrow (it's late here).

Comment: Do note that the example is a bit dangerous, main might return before `fn` runs, so the clone_args on the stack might be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example code:

```
#define stacksize 1048576  
typedef struct
{
int ii;
int jj;
} someinput1;

static int              /* Start function for cloned child */
childFunc(someinput1 *struc)
{

     printf("Child:  PID=%ld PPID=%ld\n", (long) getpid(), (long) getppid());

     printf("Hi!! I am child process created by Clone %ld \n",(long) getpid());
     printf("Value of x %d %d\n",struc->ii,struc->jj);
} 


int main()
{
someinput1 inputtest;
int i;
char *stack;                    /* Start of stack buffer */
char *stack1;                 /* End of stack buffer */
pid_t pid;


stack = malloc(stacksize);
stack1 = stack + stacksize;  

for (i = 0;i<5;i++)
{
    inputtest.ii = i+5;
    inputtest.jj = inputtest.ii + 10;
    pid = clone(childFunc, stack1, NULL,  (void *) (&inputtest));
    printf("clone returned -- %ld \n", (long) pid);
}

sleep(1);          
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```